# kubectl returning cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to patch a secret using kubectl

```
kubectl patch secret operator-secrets --namespace kube-system --context=cluster1 --patch "'{\"data\": {\"FOOBAR\": \"$FOOBAR\"}}'"
```

But I receive the error

> Error from server (BadRequest): json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}

If I run the command using echo, it seems to be a valid JSON

```
$ echo "'{\"data\": {\"FOOBAR\": \"$FOOBAR\"}}'"

'{"data": {"FOOBAR": "value that I want"}}'
```

What can be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I run the command using echo, it seems to be a valid JSON

In fact, it does not. Look carefully at the first character of the output:

```
'{"data": {"FOOBAR": "value that I want"}}'
```

Your "JSON" string starts with a single quote, which is an invalid character. To get valid JSON, you would need to rewrite your command to look like this:

```
echo "{\"data\": {\"FOOBAR\": \"$FOOBAR\"}}"
```

And we can confirm that's valid JSON using something like the `jq`
command:

```
$ echo "{\"data\": {\"FOOBAR\": \"$FOOBAR\"}}"   | jq .
{
  "data": {
    "FOOBAR": "value that i want"
  }
}
```

Making your patch command look like:

```
kubectl patch secret operator-secrets \
  --namespace kube-system \
  --context=cluster1 \
  --patch "{\"data\": {\"FOOBAR\": \"$FOOBAR\"}}"
```

But while that patch is now valid JSON, it's still going to fail with
a new error:

```
The request is invalid: patch: Invalid value: "map[data:map[FOOBAR:value that i want]]": error decoding from json: illegal base64 data at input byte 5
```

The value of items in the `data` map must be base64 encoded values.
You can either base64 encode the value yourself:

```
kubectl patch secret operator-secrets \
  --namespace kube-system \
  --context=cluster1 \
  --patch "{\"data\": {\"FOOBAR\": \"$(base64 <<<"$FOOBAR")\"}}"
```

Or use `stringData` instead:

```
kubectl patch secret operator-secrets \
  --namespace kube-system \
  --context=cluster1 \
  --patch "{\"stringData\": {\"FOOBAR\": \"$FOOBAR\"}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error

```
kubectl patch secret operator-secrets --namespace kube-system --context=standard-cluster-1 --patch "{\"data\": {\"FOOBAR\": \"$FOOBAR\"}}"
```